# Kotlin: get a Reference to a Function of a Class' instance

Tags: function, kotlin

I am trying to pass a function to a function in Kotlin here is my code.

```
fun validateValueWithFunc(value: String, parsefun: (CharSequence) -> Boolean, type: String){
    if(parsefun(value))
        print("Valid ${type}")
    else
        print("Invalid ${type}")
}
```

The function I'm passing is from Regex class "containsMatchIn"

```
val f = Regex.fromLiteral("some regex").containsMatchIn
```

I know about the :: function reference operator but I don't know how to use it in this situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.0.4, [bound callable references](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/5) (those with expressions on left-hand side) are not available yet, you can only [use class name to the left of `::`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references).

This feature is [planned for Kotlin 1.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/07/first-glimpse-of-kotlin-1-1-coroutines-type-aliases-and-more/) and will have the following syntax:

```
val f = Regex.fromLiteral("some regex")::containsMatchIn
```

Until then, you can express the same using lambda syntax. To do it, you should capture a `Regex` into a single-argument lambda function:

```
val regex = Regex.fromLiteral("some regex")
val f = { s: CharSequence -> regex.containsMatchIn(s) } // (CharSequence) -> Boolean
```

One-line equivalent using [`with(...) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html):

```
val f = with(Regex.fromLiteral("some regex")) { { s: CharSequence -> containsMatchIn(s) } }
```

<sup>Here, `with` binds the `Regex` to [receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) for the outer braces and returns the last and the only expression in the outer braces -- that is, the lambda function defined by the inner braces. See also: [the idiomatic usage of `with`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#calling-multiple-methods-on-an-object-instance-with).</sup>

Comment: maybe make it clearer that you are "wrapping" the function with a lamda to capture the instance, until bound callable references are available.  The first verison of your syntax would be hard to beginners to grok.

Comment: It's worth noting that `regex.containsMatchIn(s)` can also be expressed as `regex in s`